# My music player can play only one song?

Tags: java, audio, audio-player

I tried to make music player with Java. Its not good but I like test codes and try make music player with my own way. So my music player can play only one song/sound. There is textField where you need write you song file location. Example I can write epic.wav and its play epic.wav, then I want listen asd.wav but if I write it player still play epic.wav.

There some code from my Sound.java

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;



class Sound {

public static final Sound sound1 = new Sound(Form.soundString);


private AudioClip clip;

public Sound(String filename){
    try{
        clip = Applet.newAudioClip(Sound.class.getResource(filename));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void play(){
    try{
        new Thread(){
           public void run(){
               clip.play();
           } 
        }.start();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

And there is some code from my Form.java

```
public class Form extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public Form() {
    initComponents();
}
public static String soundString;


private Sound sound;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")



private void exitButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
System.exit(0);
}                                       

private void miniButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    this.setState(Form.ICONIFIED);
}                                       

private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        soundString = jTextField1.getText();

    Sound.sound1.play();  



}
```

So there is my codes... And i only want know why its play only one song.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do you really want to hear two or more songs at the same time?

Comment: Try to stop the clip first, `clip.stop()`

Comment: Now i fixed it:     private void PlayMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
            soundString = jTextField1.getText();
        Sound.sound1.stop();
        Sound.sound1.play();  
    }